# Reading a file that will be created in future when deploying to heroku

Tags: linux, bash, shell, heroku, lazy-evaluation

I have deployed a jar on heroku that opens a connection to a random port. When this jar is opened, it creates a config.txt file and keeps receiving request. This config.txt file has a randomly generated username and password.

The whole jar is executed using a shell script file. This file is called by heroku Procfile.

How do i tell shell script to read the content of config.txt file. This config.txt file will be automatially created by the jar.

Comment: See [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521462/5291015)